# How to manually update the entity data model?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamic, edmx

I'm writing a program that will automatically add procedure or table. How do I manually add a data model inside myself in procedure ? (manual Code behind) How do I add manual data model include procedure?

[image]

I want to do it without using a wizard. I'm looking for an example or topic.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Entity Framework ORM.

You can write all your Entity models in a cs file, then using migrations all the tables will
 will get generated in database automatically.